# Is there a mime type or file extension for a "\n" or a "Linebreak Separated Value" list?

Tags: csv, mime-types, line-breaks, mime, file-extension

If a `.csv` mime type denotes a "Comma Separated Value" list, I would like to know if there is an equivalent for a list of values, with the delimeter being a `\n` linebreak?

I would rather use this, as my values that I am listing include commas, but not linebreaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Tab Separated Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) List, with the extension `.tsv` is the best alternative, given that it uses newlines as a delimiter on rows, and tabs as a delimiter on columns.

This also will grant expandability if you wish to ever add any additonal data to each list item, and even the added benefit of being able to import the item into a database. Just make sure the first line serves as a header for each column.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds like simply `text/plain`. While this sort of formatting is common, there is no explicit standard, and so, it would probably be futile for MIME to try to articulate one which genuinely provides value for interoperablility while being flexible enough for all the various uses of "data" text files.

(CSV is a thorny counter-example because there are several mutually incompatible dialects. Still, it is *reasonably* well-standardized in that everyone will *think* they know what you mean when you say CSV.)

Comment: For what it's worth, MIME doesn't attempt to govern file extensions, as far as I am aware.

Comment: To the extent that there is meaningful standardization, it is system-dependent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension

Comment: You can always change the accepted answer if reality gets updated.